# Stock java/android sound effects

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for this forum, but are there a set of stock sound effects that are available through the Java/Android APIs? I understand how to load and play an audio file programmatically, I'm just wondering if there's any sort of large database of sound effects pre-loaded into the java/android framework. I'm specifically looking for individual notes from a bass guitar - I could record them myself but I need a couple octaves and it'd be a bit of pain to do all the recording and sound editing if there's already stock versions.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to use a MIDI instrument in order to create the individual notes, if you can't find some stock bass guitar sounds.

Comment: Intriguing idea, can you expand upon it a little bit further Vulcan? I have no experience with any of the Midi properties/functionality in Java

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used Java's MIDI functionality either; I use other software (such as FL Studio) connected to a physical MIDI controller.  A free alternative would be to use the piano roll of [Reason](http://reaper.fm/) or another free digital audio workstation.  Some online MIDI sequencers also exist, but I've never used any before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could probably be reworded to make it a more "proper" question(maybe ask specifically where in the android framework the stock sound are located, which would give you a list), but the short answer is no, you won't find any stock bass guitar sounds. Mostly all they have are the UI sounds(click/swipe/etc) along with ringtones/notification sounds.

You may be able to find some recorded sounds on the net, though, and save yourself some time that way. Even if they're not baked into the OS, I'm sure someone has recorded these sounds before. You could check sites devoted to drum kits, for example. Just be sure to check the licensing.

Comment: Huh alright. I figured it was a long shot. I've done some elementary searches that didn't yield anything particularly fruitful, but it does seem like SOMEONE must have done it already.

Comment: One of the links [here](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/12/03/free-sample-shootout-7-best-free-guitar-and-bass-samples/) might have what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow. Absolutely perfect. Thanks a ton Geobits.